# N*(connect + send + close) vs (Nagle disable + connect + N*send + close) , N > 1

Tags: c++, c, network-programming, sockets

I'm new to socket programming (as you already figure out by my silly question), but keeping my shame aside, I'm writing a program using TCP posix. My constrain is the following: The message to be sent from the client to the server,should be read as byte stream and while my application is not high performance, the message should be deliver as soon as possible. I wrote a TCP client class with the intention of doing the following:  1 connect - many send - and 1 close at the end of the streaming. The problem is that the messages does not get deliver in near-real-time (I'm assuming its waiting to have a larger package for better 
throughput) After doing some research online, I found that while you can disable the Nagle algorithm (NA), it is s a very bad idea to do so. Since I'm new on socket programming, I don't want to disable features that I don't fully understand. So I'm left with two (bad?) options:

1. connect - send- close  per message
2. 1 connect - send multiple times and do 1 close at the end with the NA disabled.
   While I read the consequences of disabling the NA,  It seems to me that opening and closing a socket every time just to send a message is an expensive price to pay as well.

Are there other solutions without leaving sockets?

Thanks.

Comment: +1 for doing good research before asking.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your case, disabling Nagle is exactly what you want to do.

Just remember that every call to write() is going to transmit your data immediately.  So be sure you are packing your entire message together and then calling write() (or writev()) once when you are ready to send; do not call write() repeatedly with small payloads because that will be slow.

Situations like yours are exactly why they let you disable Nagle.

Comment: I agree.  Disabling Nagle is waaaaaay better than doing a bunch of extra three-way handshakes, plus extra FIN packets.

Answer (score 2):

@Nemo has given great advice for TCP.

But I suggest you look at UDP instead.  TCP can introduce arbitrary delay during packet loss, and "TCP fairness" works based on forcing packet loss to occur.  It's not ideal for low-latency transfers.  Wanting to disable Nagle is a strong sign you're using the wrong protocol.

Comment: That what was my initial reaction, but the the constraint that pushed me away from UDP is data integriy. Datum have to arrive in order and correct...other wise, the app will not make sense.

Comment: @Armando: If you want timely AND correct, your choice seems to be FEC.  A simple "send multiple copies of every packet" should suffice.  With sequence numbers, you can throw away the duplicates and ensure the right order.  If multiple copies of every packet would waste too much bandwidth, you can use some error-correcting code, of which parity is the simplest (note, run it across packets, since an entire packet is likely to go away at once).

Comment: FEC = Forward Error Correction, btw - sending more information up front so that a significant number of transmission errors can be corrected receiver-side. This improves latency at the cost of bandwidth. TCP's error recovery involves resending the data, which optimizes bandwidth over latency.

Comment: @MSalters: That's exactly the idea.  Although, because UDP already has an error-detecting code, intervening routers will most likely detect errors and drop the entire packet.  So here, it's Forward *Erasure* Correction.  Codes which have good performance for error correction also have great erasure reconstruction performance, though.